# Performance issue with Cloud mongodb with Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, performance, spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I have a spring boot application with spring data mongodb

Indeed the application is running fast when mongodb is in local (normal! - started with Docker). The data import takes 90 seconds to complete in local but 35 minutes on Atlas...

I have tested like that:

1. Unit test with local mongodb which reads a json file: 90 s
2. Unit test with atlas mongodb which reads a json file: 35 minutes

I though my internet fibre connection will just double the time for my import test with atlas.

Do I miss something with the configuration in application.yml

```
  data:
    mongodb:
      uri: mongodb+srv://xxx:yyyy@zzz-cluster-m30.rmgke.mongodb.net/TOTO?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

I have also tried without SRV and listed all the nodes but I did not help.

Many thanks,

Comment: It's curious that your unit test and data import timings are exactly the same. Could you elaborate on what you're doing exactly? Post the code and the commands you did as well please. Also you mentioned fiber connection. What's your upload/download speed?

Comment: The unit test and the data import are totally independent. The inner method is the same. Someone from MongoAtlas gave me an hints with the TLS connection which is done at each insert. So I have changed my import code to gather all objects in a bulk insert and it is a lot better now.